# How to calculate days ahead or behind schedule in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, analytics

If I have a quarter target of 631 downloads then it would need to average 7 downloads a day to meet my objective in 91 days.

If I'm 41 days into the quarter and I have had 351 downloads, how many days ahead of schedule am I?

Is there a Google Sheets formula I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=(B4-B3*B2/B1)*B1/B2
```

[image: SO45620283]

The part inside the parentheses is how many *downloads* ahead/behind schedule and the fraction outside scales from downloads to days.

You should perhaps consider some mathematics education.

A couple of problems with @pjc90's answer:

1. It uses an inexact average per day (nearer `6.934` than `7`)
2. It does not make clear what is to be divided by `7` (which should be the difference `downloadCount` - `onTarget` rather than only `onTarget`).